# Lazy Load Child List Properties in DevExpress Grid (XtraGrid)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, lazy-loading

I have a simple POCO data structure with *what I believe* is the correct implementation of loading a list of children in a 'Lazy' manner.

Something like this:

```
public class Parents
{ 
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //children
    private List<Children> childrenList;
    public List<Children> ChildrenList
    {
        get
        {
            if (childrenList == null) { childrenList = Children.FindByParentID(ID); }
            return childrenList;
        }
        set childrenList = value;
    }
}
```

I need to use a DevExpress XtraGrid control to present the data as it is the control set used by my employer.

I bind the `List<Parents>` to the grid (e.g. `myGrid.DataSource = Parents.FindAll();` ) and everything is fine until I try to expand the first child list using the "+" expansion indicator on the grid.

After I try to expand the first item, the grid (I'm assuming) goes through every parent and tries to load the child list resulting in very slow performance.  I can see this while debugging.

I would like the grid to only load the child list for the single item requested.  Any ideas about how to achieve this behavior would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t438831/does-xtragrid-support-virtual-mode

Comment: @rfmodulator, thanks for the suggestion but, I don't think that's going to work for me.  I'm trying to implement a clean C# only POCO datalayer so multiple upper tier apps can be written on top of it.  Bringing in a bunch of devexpress wrapper code wouldn't be beneficial here.  I've always used infragistics grid in the past without issue but, I'm new to the devexpress grid and it seems to have some troubles handling hierarchical data without some weird proprietary data source or wrapper classes.  Thanks